# yii2-redis find() returns empty results

Tags: php, redis, yii2

I have the following simple model:

```
<?php

namespace app\models;

use Yii;
use yii\base\Model;
use \yii\redis\ActiveRecord;
use \yii\db\ActiveQuery;

class StatsModel extends ActiveRecord
{

    public function attributes()
    {
        return ['user'];
    }
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            ['user' : 'string']
        ];
    }
    public static function getDb()
    {

        return \Yii::$app->db_redis;
    }
}
```

`\Yii::$app->db_redis;` is a config in web.php:

```
<?php

return [
    'class' => 'yii\redis\Connection',
    'hostname' => 'localhost',
    'port'     => 6379,
    'database' => 0

];
```

I do in the redis-cli:

```
127.0.0.1:6379> select 0
OK
127.0.0.1:6379> hmset key123 user michael
OK
127.0.0.1:6379>
```

But when i do `$test = \app\models\StatsModel::find()->all();` inside layout view i see in the xdebug debugger, that it returns empty set, like there are no records inside redis. I can't understand why, i just added a user and a key to database with index 0. Can someone explain it

Comment: dont you have to specify your primary key inside the `attributes` ? https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2-redis/blob/master/docs/guide/usage-ar.md

Comment: @MuhammadOmerAslam just tried,  i have changed attributes to this: `return ['id','user'];`  then i have done this: `hmset key5555 id 1 user papapapa` still empty result

Comment: @MuhammadOmerAslam  `$test = StatsModel::find()->where(['user' => 'papapapa'])->one();` $test is null

Comment: https://medium.com/@stockholmux/from-sql-to-redis-chapter-1-145c82e4baa0

Answer (score 1):

`ActiveRecord` for redis uses dedicated structure and multiple keys to store data about models. Don't expect that you can push some data with random keys and it will be interpreted as active record model. `StatsModel::find()->all()` does not return anything, because you've not created any model - you've pushed some data to redis, but this is not a active record model. You should use `ActiveRecord` to save model, if you want to use it with `StatsModel::find()`:

```
$model = new StatsModel();
$model->id = 1;
$model->user = 'rob006';
$model->save();

$result = StatsModel::find()->all(); // finds one model
```

Or don't use `ActiveRecord` and use queries directly:

```
$result = Yii::$app->db_redis->hget('key123', 'user'); // "michael"
```